# Ionic Framework SideMenu remove item using ng-hide not working?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a sidemenu that has a login list which redirects  to login pages and after the user login successfull i want the login to diappear, Instead the login i want to show logout and other user functionality. I try using ng-hide but is not working

[image]

I want the result to be like this after login. I assign the false value to ng-hide in login function but the value is changed but does seems to change the view.

I want the result be like this :-

[image]

Index.html

```
<body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="loginCtrl">
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="true">
    <ion-side-menu side="left">
            <div class="list card">
                <div class="item item-image">
                    <img ng-src="img/sideImage.png">
                </div>
            </div>
            <ion-list>
                <ion-item menu-close ui-sref="mainlist" ui-sref-active="active">
                    Home 
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item menu-close ui-sref="login" ng-hide="menuItem" ui-sref-active="active">
                    Login
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item menu-close ui-sref="mainlist" ng-hide="!menuItem" ui-sref-active="active" ng-click="logOut()">
                    Log Out
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item menu-close ui-sref="userpage" ng-hide="!menuItem" ui-sref-active="active">
                    MyBlog
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item menu-close ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="about">
                    About
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item menu-close ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="postblog">
                    Post blog <! -- delete this -->
                </ion-item>
            </ion-list> 
        </ion-side-menu>

        <ion-side-menu-content>
        <!-- Main content, usually <ion-nav-view> -->
            <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
                  <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
                   <!-- Toggle left side menu -->
                   <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
                  </ion-nav-buttons>
                </ion-nav-bar>
            <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-side-menu-content>
</ion-side-menus>
```

app.js

```
blog.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider        
        .state('login',{
        url:'/login',
        templateUrl:'templates/login.html',
        controller:'loginCtrl'
    })
```

Controller.js (not all of the code)

```
blog.controller('loginCtrl',function($scope,$state,$firebaseAuth,$cordovaToast)
            {
                    $scope.menuItem = false;
                    var fbAuth= $firebaseAuth(fb);
                    $scope.data={};

                    //login Code
                    $scope.login=function(username,password){
                             var username = $scope.data.username;
                             var password = $scope.data.password;
                             if(username && password !=null)
                                {
                                    fbAuth.$authWithPassword({email:username,password:password})
                                    .then(function (authData)
                                          {  
                                        $scope.menuItem = true;
                                        console.log($scope.menuItem);
                                          $state.go('userpage');
                                           // $cordovaToast.showShortBottom("Login Successful");
                                            console.log("loged in" +authData.uid);
                                            uid =authData.uid;
                                            console.log(uid);


                                          })
                                    .catch(function (error)
                                           {
                                          //  $cordovaToast.showShortBottom("Login Fail");
                                            console.log("oops something went wrong"+error);  
                                        })
                                }
                             else
                                {
                                  //  $cordovaToast.showShortBottom("enter username & password");
                                    console.log("must enter username and password"); 
                                }
                    }
```

menuItem the ng-hide boolean value.
im using the loginCtrl in both template page index.html and login.html as the same controller so that i dont have to pass value around.

Edit:
the Login in the side menu redirect to this page :
[image]

and the login button here calls the login function inside the controller.

ps: im just a beginner ,i know the style and design pattern sucks i should have used services or factory.

Answer (score 0):

use $rootScope varaible ex: $rootScope.menuitem instead of $scope.menuitem

Answer (score 0):

Try using [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

```
$scope.menuItem = false;
```

you see making the condition false will make that area disappear and when making it true it will appear look in the above code

```
<ion-item menu-close ui-sref="login" ng-hide="menuItem" ui-sref-active="active" ng-if="$scope.menuItem = false;">
   Login
</ion-item>
<ion-item menu-close ui-sref="mainlist" ng-hide="!menuItem" ui-sref-active="active" ng-click="logOut()" ngif="$scope.menuItem = true;">
   Log Out
</ion-item>
```